# How to use Groupby query in odata v4 with Microsoft.AspNet.OData 5.9.1?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata

In old version of Asp.net.odata(5.3.1) I was using groupby & aggregation query by writing custom function in my Web API project.

But in latest Web.Odata dll (5.9.1), it's provide built in support of aggregation and groupby.
[Aggregation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html)

But when I am using groupby query, my web api service is throwing odata exception.

**example** : -- http://localhost:51738/odata/Document?$apply=groupby((Id))